# Error regenerating R.java file after refactoring (moving) a project folder in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, refactoring, directory

My current Android project structure in IntelliJ is free.nrw.commons, but I need to change it to fr.free.nrw.commons. I created the 'fr' folder and used the refactor tool to move 'free.nrw.commons' into the 'fr' folder, but this seemed to break the links to the layout files, for example `resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text` produces the error 'cannot resolve symbol R'.

So I deleted the R.java file and regenerated it, but this did not solve the problem and I get the error `Error:android-apt-compiler: [commons] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\misao\Documents\GitHub\apps-android-commons\commons\res java` when I try to rebuild.

I have also read similar StackOverflow threads and tried these steps, to no avail:
(1) Invalidate cache and restart, and 
(2) Checked for any false android.R imports that might block regeneration.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post the content and structure of your res/ folder

Comment: It's too long to post here, but it's on GitHub. https://github.com/misaochan/apps-android-commons/tree/master/commons/res

Comment: Alternatively, does anyone know a way to modify the project folder structure to accommodate changing the package name from free.nrw.commons to fr.free.nrw.commons, without using the 'move' tool that seems to break things? Renaming appears to work fine, but can't just do that when there are 4 folder tiers needed instead of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem. When doing the Refactor>Move, I needed to select the 'move entire directory' option, not the 'move package' option.