# Altering project directory structure in IntelliJ IDEA to fit package names

Tags: android, intellij-idea, directory, directory-structure, intellij-13

I am trying to contribute to an existing open source Android project, and came across a bug where the package names listed in the code says `package fr.free.nrw.commons;` whereas the actual project directory structure in the IntelliJ IDEA is free/nrw/commons. The package name in the code needs to stay, as that is the name that the app is published under. So the folder structure needs to change.

I have tried simply creating a 'fr' folder and moving everything into it via refactor > move, but that causes problems with the R.java file regeneration that I described at [Error regenerating R.java file after refactoring (moving) a project folder in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932497/error-regenerating-r-java-file-after-refactoring-moving-a-project-folder-in-in) . I am no closer to finding a solution for that problem, so I'm wondering if I'm just going about everything the wrong way. Is there another way to alter the project folder structure without using the messy 'move' refactor tool?

Comment: Check if `Android Studio` changed package names in `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files. If the names were not updated then do it manually, clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Thanks, but the project is in IntelliJ IDEA and not Android Studio. I typically use Android Studio myself, but for this project I am trying to stick to IntelliJ as converting to Android Studio would change the file structure of everything and might be detrimental for the other contributors.